# Flutter translate API data

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-localizations

I have an API that include 17.000 words. I show this words on a flipcard on the screen. When the back of card, I want translated versions of these words. How can I do that? Do I use Yandex translate API? I tried to use Google translate API but it couldn't work.

```
Future<dynamic> fetchAPIdata() async {
    //API cagrisi
    try {
      final url = Uri.parse('https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/all');
      final response = await http.get(url);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        if (responseData is List<dynamic>?) {
          data.addAll(
              responseData?.map((e) => e?.toString() ?? "").toList() ?? []);
          word_box.addAll(data);
          isBusy.value = false;
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (_) {
      isBusy.value = false;
    }
  }
```

```
child: CardSwiper(
                                backCardOffset: const Offset(0, 27.0),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                numberOfCardsDisplayed: 3,
                                isLoop: true,
                                onEnd: () {
                                  controller.listNext();
                                },
                                onSwipe:
                                    (previousIndex, currentIndex, direction) {
                                  index = currentIndex ?? previousIndex;
                                  return Future.value(true);
                                },
                                controller: controller.cardSwiperController,
                                cardsCount: controller.list.length,
                                cardBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return FlipCard(
                                    controller: controller.flipCardController,
                                    side: CardSide.FRONT,
                                    direction: FlipDirection.HORIZONTAL,
                                    back: Card(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                      color: UIColors.primary400,
                                      child: Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        child: Text( '${controller.list[index]}'.trParams({
                                          'words': controller.list[index],
                                        }),
                                          style: UIStyle.h1,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    front: Card(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                      color: UIColors.primary400,
                                      child: Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              controller.list[index],
                                              style: UIStyle.h1,
                                            ),
                                            Text('TEXT',
                                                style: UIStyle.sh2_medium
                                                    .copyWith(
                                                        color:
                                                            UIColors.grey100)),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
```

```
body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Text(
              'textArea'.tr(),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              onPressed: () {
                translator.setNewLanguage(
                  context,
                  newLanguage: translator.currentLanguage == 'ar' ? 'en' : 'ar',
                  remember: true,
                  restart: true,
                );
              },
              child: Text('buttonTitle'.tr()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I tried this but it couldn't work so I deleted code. I have button and when I click the button card is flipping then must show translated version of word.